# how can I create an indicator that combine two fundamental value on pinescript e.g. free cashflow + book value

Tags: pine-script

tradingview provides many types of screener.. is it possible to integrate those screener value as a part of the valuation in a strategy/study

I have not seen any of the online manual covering the discussion for fundamental values available in the screener

has anyone done something like this on tradingview using pinescript?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
study("My Script")
fcf = financial (syminfo.tickerid, "FREE_CASH_FLOW", "FQ")
plot(fcf)
```

More info you can find [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/?solution=43000564727#fun_financial)